# How do I run two functions at once using Asyncio in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

```py
queue = []

async def funcA():
    r = random.randint(0, 1000)
    i = 0
    for i in range(10000000):
        pass
    print(r)
    queue.append(r)

    asyncio.create_task(funcb(r))

async def funcb(r):
    i = 0
    for i in range(100000000):
        pass
    print(r, "XX")
    queue.pop()


async def main():
    for i in range(10):
        await funcA()
    print(queue)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

How do I make `funcb()` run simultaneously? In this code `funcb()` runs only after all calls of `funcA()` are done executing. I want `funcB()` to run concurrently with `funcA()` (on same or different threads). Here if `funcA()` runs infinitely, then `funcB()` would never run.

Comment: They’re both blocking functions, they don’t yield/await anything internally. Even if you start them together, they can only be executed one after the other. For parallel execution, you need threading.

Comment: You might be able to use [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html) but as other people say this isn't something you really want to do with asyncio

Comment: Wouldn't mind hearing back from you and getting a checkmark if you found my answer helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asyncio is a so-called [non-preemptive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)) task scheduler.

This means, it cannot switch back and forth between tasks on its own, it requires the function it is calling to actively give up (=yield) the priority.

As your function is not asynchronous (= doesn't have any commands in it that would wait for something with the `await` keyword), it just runs to completion before yielding back to the asyncio scheduler.

The way you described your problem sounds like it isn't really suitable for asynchronous programming, but instead requires multithreading or even multiprocessing (if you desire to get a speedup from the 'simultaneous' computing).